# How to deal with "StaleObjectStateException" in Hibernate with pessimistic locking?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

**Edit:**
It turns out in this case since I was using "version" annotation, so I'm using optimistic locking, not pessimistic locking.
If I remove version and hence disable optimistic locking.  The pessimistic locking takes over and performance degraded significantly. 
So I guess I have to live with optimistic locking and occasional exceptions.  Is there a better solution?

**Original:**
I currently have multiple tomcat instances in an apache 2.2 load balancer via ajp.  The backend system is hibernate.  The system serves multiple users and requests, for request it deducts one credit from the user's account.

I use hibernate's pessimistic locking for managing credit deductions.
I kept getting the following from time to time on user account object in the logs:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

**Code**

```
private boolean decUserAccountQuota(UserAccount userAccount, int creditDec) {

        if(userAccount.getBalance() <1) return false;
        String userName = userAccount.getUsername();
        Manager manager = getManager(userName);


        try{
            manager.beginTransaction();
            manager.refresh(userAccount, LockMode.UPGRADE); //this uses pessimistic locking, this calls sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().refresh();   
            userAccount.setBalance(userAccount.getBalance()-creditDec);
            manager.commitTransaction(); //this causes the Exception
        }catch(Exception exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
            manager.rollbackTransaction();
            return false;
        }finally{
            manager.closeSession();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I prevent this exception from happening.  What happens here
   is more than one threads tries to update the same entity, one thread
   succeeds and hence, when the next thread goes to commit the data, it
   sees that its already been modified and ends up throwing
   StaleObjectStateException.  But if I'm already using pessimistic
   locking, how can the exception still happen?
2. Are there any better ways in terms of performance and integrity in
   managing the user account credit system?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you are actually using optimistic locking? The difference is described at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html.

Comment: @Gustav Grusell:please see the update

Comment: Is there a `<version>` in `userAccount` mapping on a field annotated as `@Version` ? If yes, hibernate will do optimistic locking between transactions.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta:should I remove version and optimistic locking?

Comment: Your exception is weird anyway, because in a single transaction you do a select, modify, update which should always work. What is the `Manager` class ?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta: Manager in most cases are like sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Comment: @user121196 Since your DB doesnot support SELECT .. FOR UPDATE your code manager.refresh(userAccount, LockMode.UPGRADE) is not taking the pessimistic locking and is resorting to optimistic locking. How to get pessimistic locking inspite of database not supporting is something which needs to be checked. Sorry I couldnt help much here.

Answer (score 0):

Your Hibernate entity is either using `@Version` annotation or defines `<version>` in your XML Hibernate mapping. This will enable the optimistic locking provided by Hibernate.

If you are explicitly using pessimistic locking as you described, removing the above should  fix your problem.

More info [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html)

Comment: is it safe to remove optimistic locking elsewhere? decUserAccountQuota is the only transaction that does the write.  But there are other transactions that does reads before, during and after this method.

Comment: Based on your edit it seems your original question has been answered. Living with Optimistic locking is not too bad. In fact, usually, it is the preferred choice as compared to Pessimistic locking since it scales well and works particularly well in Read-Often Write-Sometimes situations (as mentioned in Hibernate docs). One reason I can think of for using pessimistic locking is when you want to know of failure "early" in the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the below line is not taking a pessimistic lock, although you are specifying it to, because your database doesnot support SELECT.. FOR UPDATE .

```
manager.refresh(userAccount, LockMode.UPGRADE);
```

For this reason hibernate uses an alternate mode of locking called LockMode.READ for userAccount which is optimistic locking based on the @Version attribute in your entity.

I searched to see if there is any alternative way of forcing hibernate to take pessimistic locking for your scenario but it looks like its not possbile.

Coming back to your question of how to minimize or avoid the StaleObjectStateException here are my thoughts:-

Synchronize on userAccount object . Though this seems to affect performance but this would happen only if the same user places too many concurrent requests. Also giving up a little on performance to make sure that user need not be thrown an exception and made to retry would be ideal scenario.

If you have found any alternative solution please do share it .

Comment: after changing manager.refresh(userAccount,LockMode.UPGRDE) to manager.lock(userAccount, LockMode.UPGRADE);  the StaleObjectStateException now occurs frequently on the manager.lock.  I guess it's because the userAccount was optmistically locked by earlier reads. any solution?

Comment: @user121196 Sorry about that. Just a check does your DB support SELECT .. FOR UPDATE option and what is the dialect which you are using for DB